# How did the Doctor return to the present?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, doctor-who

In "Before the flood" (S09E04), when the damn breaks and security protocol 712 is activated in the Tardis, I'm assuming it returned to the present (year 2119 where Clara is) with Bennett.

How did the Doctor return? Did he sleep till the year 2119 in suspension chamber in the space hearse? If not how else did he wake up in it?

Comment: Do you even know what a suspension chamber is? Because what you describe is exactly its purpose.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I know. But it's hard to believe he slept for more than 100 years. And they didn't even acknowledge it in the episode.

Comment: You don't seem to grasp the concept of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspended_animation . Also, the Dr is 2000+ years old.

Comment: @BCdotWEB And you don't seem to grasp my question. My doubts are not over the working of a suspension chamber.

Comment: Then ***what*** is your question? I mean, here's the relevant dialog: `"And saying the chamber will open?" "That was me telling me to get inside and when to set it for."`

Comment: There you go. That answered my question.

Comment: Related question on Sci-Fi and Fantasy: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/104960/23386

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Doctor got Back to Future™ the long way around, by hibernating in the [suspended animation chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspended_animation) in the space-hearse.

> **Bennett:** *The **suspended animation chamber** is still here, and the power cells for the engine.*
>
> ... [later]
>
> **Clara:** *And saying the chamber will open?*
>
> **The Doctor:** *That was me telling me to get inside and when to set it for.*

[image]

Comment: Nice. Mind if I pinch this gif and use it in my SFF answer?

Comment: @randal'thor - By all means.